# Eclipse File>Import "Other" missing  for Maven 2 plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

In attempting to follow the instructions on [Using Eclipse with Maven](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Using_Eclipse_with_Maven) in order to use [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [Lift](http://liftweb.net/):

> You’ll need to download and install Eclipse for Java or Java EE.

I first installed [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) on [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) 11.10 using the [Synaptic Package Mananger](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/).
The version I am using is "Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.0 Build id: I20110613-1736". Then the instructions say to install M2Eclipse:

> Then install the M2Eclipse, Scala IDE, and M2Eclipse-Scala plugins.

So I followed the link to [M2Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration) where there is a video which says to use "File>Import" which should display a list of choices which includes "Other" in the "Import" window. These instructions are at time stamp "00:55" in the video. My "Import" window only lists "-General -CVS -Install-Pligin -Plugin-Development -Run/Debug -Team".

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure M2Eclipse installed successfully? And did you restart Eclipse?

Comment: No, the failure is on the first step in attempting to install M2Eclipse, File>Import.

Comment: The first step already assumes maven2 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Eclipse versions have Maven2 preinstalled. You can check if it is installed in Eclipse via menu `Help > About Eclipse`. Check if there is an icon with the text m2, or alternatively click on "Installation details" and check the "Features" tab.

After you've installed it you will have new options in the `File > Import` menu.

Install M2Eclipse via menu `Help > Install new software`. Then click on the add button and add a site with location http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e. Wait until contents are retrieved and check the items you want to install.

Comment: "After you've installed it", what is it and how? Every google just seems to lead back to the m2e location.

Comment: "It" is m2eclipse and I explained how to install it in my answer. You can also check [this page](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) for more details on how to install m2eclipse